# Best way to adapt a factory method to an interface

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, factory

I'm trying to create the skeleton of a basic framework, but I've stumbled on a situation in which I find myself with some piece of the engine that is missing.

I have this class to manage MySQL connections:

```
class Mysql implements IConnection {

    protected $user;
    protected $pass;
    protected $dbhost;
    protected $dbname;
    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct($user, $pass, $dbhost, $dbname)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public function prepare($query)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Now I want to use a factory + singleton to manage a sole instance of this class:

```
class Database
{
    private static $db;

    private function __construct() {}

    public function getInstance($DBType = 'mysql') 
    {
        if (! isset(self::$db)) {
            switch ($DBType) {
                case 'mysql':
                    self::$db = new Mysql(); // <---- PROBLEM HERE!!
                // more database types should follow
            }
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

Note that this way I should pass the factory method the connection parameters everytime I needed the database connection instance, which definitely wouldn't be convenient.

The only thing that comes to mind is to pass the db connection, previously created, to Mysql::__construct() and store it in a property, in order to use in within Mysql::prepare(), but it would break the interface: Mysql::connect() wouldn't make any sense, and I couldn't have the db connection wrapped in this class together with the query management.

What would you suggest me to do?

**EDIT:** 
This is my own try, although I would need to change the interface, and I'm not sure if it would be a good approach: 
- Changing the interface so that IConnection::connect() accepts the connection parameters instead of the constructor

```
class Mysql implements IConnection {

    protected $dbh; // now I only need this property

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function connect($user, $pass, $dbhost, $dbname)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public function prepare($query)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

And the Singleton Factory:

```
class Database
{
    private static $db;

    private function __construct() {}

    public function getInstance($DBType = 'mysql') 
    {
        if (! isset(self::$db)) {
            switch ($DBType) {
                case 'mysql':
                    self::$db = new Mysql;
                    break;
                case 'mssql':
                    self::$db = new Mssql;
                    break;
                case 'postgresql':
                    self::$db = new Postgresql;
                    break;
                // etc
            }
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

I think this way is clean enough. Some client code:

```
$db = Database::getInstance(Config::get('db_driver'));
$db->connect(Config::get('db_user'),
             Config::get('db_pass'),
             Config::get('db_host'),
             Config::get('db_name'));
```

Suggestions and corrections are most welcome.